# how to read a long string from a file into an array or something similar?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

So I have searched for quite a while and found nothing that solves my problem currently I have a mess of a code from my previous problem, can someone attempt to tidy this so it works or simply remake it, I have 4 different text files to read from depending on what it is so the switch statement was my best idea and I intend to keep that bit. Just to add this code does not work.. .and can't work out why not.

```
ifstream QuestionFile;
int i = 0;
switch (x){
case 1:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic1 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 2:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic2 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 3:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic3 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 4:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic4 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
}
stringstream buffer;
buffer << QuestionFile.rdbuf();
string test = buffer.str();

size_t pos1 = 0;
size_t pos2;

if (!QuestionFile)
{
    cout << "Cannot load file" << endl;
}
else
{
    if (QuestionFile.peek() != ifstream::traits_type::eof()) {
        while (!QuestionFile.eof())
        {
            pos2 = test.find("|", pos1);
            questions[i] = test.substr(pos1, (pos2 - pos1));
            cout << questions[i];
            i++;
        }
        QuestionFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your programming language?

Comment: Looks like C++ to me, and it's tagged as such.

Comment: I tagged it C++, so helloflash couldn't have seen the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'd like to keep the switch statement, try this:

```
const char   *filename;
size_t       pos;
size_t       oldPos;
stringstream buffer;
string       test;

filename = NULL;
switch(x)
{
  case 0:
    filename = "Topic1 Questions.txt";
    break;
  case 1:
    filename = "Topic2 Questions.txt";
    break;
  case 2:
    filename = "Topic3 Questions.txt";
    break;
  case 3:
    filename = "Topic4 Questions.txt";
    break;
}

QuestionFile.open(filename, ios::app);   // try opening the file
if(QuestionFile.is_open())               // if open succeeds...
{
    buffer << QuestionFile.rdbuf();
    test = buffer.str();                 // read entire file into 'test'
    pos = 0;                             // start at beginning
    do
    {
        oldPos = pos;
        pos = test.find("|", oldPos);    // find position of next line
        questions[i] = test.substr(oldPos, (pos - oldPos));  // put in array
        i++;
    }
    while(pos != oldPos);  // as long as pos2 changes.
    QuestionFile.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Cannot load file" << endl;
}
```

Note: I have **not** allocated an array for you, so you still need to do this yourself.

Comment: This is for a bit of an assignment and this is the general way I'd do it so avoiding making it look to different to how I know how to do it or should know, hence why I said I want to keep the switch statement as that should work fine anyway and seems to.

Comment: I recommend not opening the file in a switch statement, as a general rule, because it breaks the program structure (see the flow example on how reading a file is usually done). -Also it seems that you start by reading the entire file, then after that, you check if there's more to read and there you try to read the lines. You'll never get into that part of the code.

Comment: Sorry but the second bit didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer (while you were posting yours). It may still be helpful, as I believe parts of it are still relevant; especially opening the file once, testing if the file opened and closing the file, which is not always happening in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so solved this myself in the end was actually really simple... so just in case anyone else comes across this and doesn't find a simple answer I've done it like this instead.

```
ifstream QuestionFile;
int i = 0;
//switch statement for checking which text file I personally wanted to use as it 
//depending on which the user was allowed to use.
switch (x){
case 1:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic1 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 2:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic2 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 3:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic3 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
case 4:
    QuestionFile.open("Topic4 Questions.txt", ios::app);
    break;
}
if (!QuestionFile)
{
    cout << "Cannot load file" << endl;
}
else
{
    if (QuestionFile.peek() != ifstream::traits_type::eof()) {
        while (!QuestionFile.eof())
        {
            //This simply gets which ever line you want and puts it into that part of the array
            //and does this till the end of the array.
            getline(QuestionFile, questions[i]);
            i++;
        }
        QuestionFile.close();
    }
}
```